# Find the volume of the solid formed by rotating completely about x-axis the area enclosed by a curve

Tags: calculus, integration

**Question:**

Find the volume of the solid formed by rotating completely about $x$-axis the area enclosed by a curve.

**My answer:**

I drew the curve and the area formed it is between $-2$ and $0$ (the rest of the curve after zero goes to infinite)

I calculated:

> $$V=\pi\int_{-2}^0[x^3-2x^2]^2\,\mathrm dx=\pi\int_{-2}^0x^5-2x^4=\pi\int\dfrac{x^6}6-\dfrac{2x^5}5$$

I plug in the values (as shown bellow) and I get $-23\pi$ the correct answer should be $128\pi/105$. What am I doing wrong here? thank you

[image]

UPDATE: the region bound is actually between 2 and 0 not -2 and 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did a very strange job! $$\int (x^3-2x^2)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x\neq\int(x^5-2x^4) \, \mathrm{d}x$$ Indeed: $$\int (x^3-2x^2)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{7}x^7-\frac{2}{3}x^6+\frac{4}{5}x^5+C$$ so $$V=\int_0^2\pi y^2 \, \mathrm{d}x=\pi \cdot \left(\frac{1}{7}2^7-\frac{2}{3}2^6+\frac{4}{5}2^5\right)-\pi(0)=\pi\times\frac{128}{105}$$

[image]

Comment: should it be 4x^4 then

Comment: Assuming the right integral for evaluating the volume is $\int_0^2 (x^3-2x^2)^2dx$ then you should focus to do $\int (x^6-4x^5+4x^4)dx$ instead.

Comment: how did you drive this?

Comment: @CashVai: Form this `(a-b)^2=a^2-2a*b+b^2`.

Comment: oh thank you! second time making the same mistake!

Comment: it's still wrong though :/

Comment: @CashVai: Why? where is the problem? tell me. :-)

Comment: This deserves a thumb's up, B.S.! +1

Comment: @Michael: could you perhaps elaborate a bit more maybe showing how to go about it cause I don't get what you are saying

Comment: @B.S.: when I plug in the values it gives the wrong answer still

Comment: Nice work, my friend!

Comment: @B.S.: nice work indeed I didn't want you to go trough all this trouble but thank you! I did get the correct integration after your first hint but I don't know why I don't get the same result when I plug in the values. Oh well